# About parsing JSON and caching data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, caching

I some JS similar to in an externally loaded file:

```
var LiveStuff = (function(){

    var LiveStuffObj = {};

    function LiveFunction(){
        console.log(LiveStuffObj.hello);
    }

    function LiveStuff(jsonData){

        LiveStuffObj = $.parseJSON(jsonData);

        $('#button').on('event', function(){
            LiveFunction();
        });
    }
);
```

where I initialize using jQuery's ready event later in the page:

```
$(function(){ var live_Stuff = new LiveStuff('{"data1":123,"data2":456}'); }
```

My goal here is to only have to parse the JSON string once, caching the LiveStuffObj object and using it each time it's needed. Things work, but I keep coming across conflicting information as to how JS and jQuery store/cache information.

My questions are: Is this doing what I think it's doing? Is there a better way such as somehow utilizing jQuery's $.data()?

Comment: Why are you passing a string in the first place? You should pass a raw object literal.

Comment: Well, the library is static of course and the JSON string is built at run-time depending on the properties of certain page elements spread across multiple views (Zend). Not how I should approach it?